# I am using in_app_purchase package what should i select in Financial features section in google play console

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

I am using in app purchase in flutter by in_app_purchase package, what should I choose in financial features section in google play console?

What should I choose ?

what should I select from financial features list provided from google play console?

if anyone try this can help me, please.

Comment: Financial features are where your app is linked to real money such as loans, banking, gambling, rewards, crypto etc. If your app is related to any of the mentioned segments you need to comply & agree with financial features & if you do not deal anything with financial products you can choose no and proceed forward

Comment: thank for your answer.
No is correct answer for my question.

Comment: @Tarek_ElsaWy Hi, Did you get any feedback from Google for your answer? Is it accepted?